# Selenium 4 chrome devtools using Python fetch.fail_request not failing the request but keeping it as pending

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-devtools-protocol, selenium4

In the following sample code the fail_request is not failing the request but simply keeping it as pending. I have similar issues with get_response_body or fulfill_request.

However all requests that are let to continue (using continue_request) are without any issues.

The import for GeneralFunctions is used for a function that returns a driver object with predefined actions. The import for testSetup provides access to generally used variables.

Is there something that I am doing wrong or is this a Selenium issue when using it with Python?

- Python version: 3.10
- Selenium webdriver version: 4.3.0
- Webdriver-manager version: 3.8.0 (used to download the latest chrome driver).
- Trio version: 0.20.0
- Chrome version: 103

```
import trio
import time
from Setup.Setup import testSetup
from Setup.General import GeneralFunctions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
generalFunctions = GeneralFunctions()
async def main1():
    driver = generalFunctions.newChrome(testSetup.url)
    time.sleep(6)
    async with driver.bidi_connection() as connection:        
        session, devtools = connection.session, connection.devtools
        await session.execute(devtools.fetch.enable())
        listener = session.listen(devtools.fetch.RequestPaused)
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            driver.refresh()
            async for event in listener:
                if "userData" in str(event.request.url) and event.request.method == "GET":
                    try:
                         await session.execute(devtools.fetch.fail_request(event.request_id, '{"error_reason": "aaaa"}'))
                        
                    except:
                        print("problem with target request")
                else:
                    try:
                        await session.execute(devtools.fetch.continue_request(event.request_id))
                    except:
                        print("problem with regular request")


async def main2():
    await main1()


trio.run(main2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by myself - I was not checking the exception error and the problem was that fetch.fail_request requires the second parameter to be something like that:

```
await session.execute(devtools.fetch.fail_request(event.request_id, devtools.network.ErrorReason.FAILED))
```